# Trying to hide a button, it's text and icon when link not present

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide a button when the link within the button is not found or the link value is "none". With the code below I'm seeing the text and link have been removed but part of the button is still visible. [This is what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3z9u.jpg)

```css
div.trailer button a[href="None"] {
  display: none;
}

div.trailer button a[href^="http:"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="trailer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="none" target=”_blank”><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>Trailer</a></button></div>
```

I dont know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `href="None"` != `href="none"`

Comment: There's no parent selector in CSS, so your code (if you fix your typo) will hide the anchor but not the anchor's parent, the button.

Comment: Ahh ok so it has no concept on it's parent - the div above? So there is no way to do this in CSS? Must be a jquery thing then

Comment: i think you forget to that css case sensitive :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As technophyle said, you can't modify the parent element of the anchor using css so when the anchor gets hidden, you're left with the button. However, if you remove the button and make the anchor look like a button it should work well. And of course make the href's match. You have the selector as "None" and the href on the anchor as "none". Here it is with that corrected and with style added to the anchor:

```css
div.trailer a[href="none"] {
  display: none;
}

div.trailer a[href^="http:"] {
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0,#e0e0e0 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="trailer"><a href="none" target=”_blank”><i class="fab fa-youtube"> 
</i>Trailer</a></div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you so much for explaining it so simply. My button styles are from the Bootstrap framework. I dont suppose there is any way to reference a style in another style sheet? 

Otherwise I can just copy over the styles for the button.

Comment: You're using bootstrap? That's perfect. Remove all the extra css that I added and just add the btn classes to the anchor so: <a class="btn btn-primary"  href="none" target=”_blank”><i class="fab fa-youtube"> 
</i>Trailer</a>... The css I used is actually copied over from the bootstrap button.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve what you want, you need to be able to hide the button based on its child's (`a` element) attribute.

Unfortunately, this is not possible with just CSS because [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#Limitations), selectors are unable to ascend.

You can implement what you want to do with a simple JavaScript though:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href="none"]').forEach(el =>
  el.parent.classList.add('hidden')
);
```

And then add a `.hidden` CSS.

Answer (score 1):

1. fix your html structure, have link inside a button is not correct and some browsers have problem with!
   make it like a normal link tag and give the style of a button to your  element
2. Maybe it's good idea to keep hide all links and show the only ones that has correct href format, like what you did !

   div.trailer a { display:none; }

   div.trailer a[href^='href:']{ display:block; }

Comment: Adding to your point 1. Having a button that in fact is a link also affects accessibility, since screen readers rely on semantic html.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with HTML structure. I wasn't aware of this!